# In Drupal, how can I create a front page with a set of menus as the content?

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules

This website http://nationalstrategies.standards.dcsf.gov.uk/ appears to be using Drupal, and I like the menu system on the front page, but can't work out how it's been done.

Has anyone any ideas about which Drupal modules might reproduce this look and functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like the Panels module
http://drupal.org/project/panels

You can create mini panels and create multi column pages that include other small pieces of content.

Edit: Looking at the source of the page they are running drupal and they are using panels module (included /sites/all/modules/panels/js/panels.js)

-Ed

Answer (score 0):

I managed to recreate the style using the taxonomy, views and panels.

A view was created for a specific taxonomy term, and then this was turned into a block and shown on a panel.

Seems to work quite well.